# Is it possible to prune only out of date files and jobs from a Bacula volume?

Tags: bacula

Our setup of Bacula uses a file device for storage, but we only have one volume.  It's 6TB, and it's about to run out of space.  The goal of the configuration it to purge jobs and files in the volume that are past retention, but not to delete the entire volume.  Is there a way to setup Bacula to do this, or will I have to recycle the entire volume to add anything new to it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you will have to recycle it, this is the way Bacula is designed.